# d3 v4 forceSimulation nodes no longer move after restart()

Tags: d3.js

As an exercise in understanding how d3 works I've been building this up from scratch, cobbled together from various examples I've found.

My problem that I can't seem to get to the bottom of is is that the nodes can no longer be dragged or even move after the data has been refreshed.  The lines refresh, just not the nodes.  The effect is more obvious if you drag some of the nodes around before submitting the form again.

Example below demonstrates the problem, I've commented out the WebSocket code I was using locally and replaced with some static data

you'll need to view it full screen :

http://bl.ocks.org/d4rr3ll/68713a42d59f5bb086ad25d5a0bcbad1

Any help appreciated

Edited to add:

So my temporary solution for now is to remove all the nodes from the SVG before the update, it's not ideal though.

```
function update_graph(data) {
    svg.selectAll(".node").remove();
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After merging the updates, you're not assigning the merged results back to your node and link.

```
link = link.merge(line)
node = node.merge(circle)
```